# Validar valor de variable retornado desde Controller C# en archivo JS(JQuery)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, controller

tengo una función en un archivo javascript, dentro de un proyecto en ASP.NET, en la cual en una parte del código de esta función se utiliza "**$.ajax()**" para realizar una llamada a un primer método que se encuentra en uno de los **controladores C#** que posee el proyecto. Este primer método que esta en el controlador retorna un numero entero, con lo cual, necesito validar en javascript que este numero retornado sea igual a un valor asignado (en este caso 1) y si se cumple la condición, que se ejecute otra llamada a un segundo método del controlador C# que retorna un json que llena una gridview en una de las vistas. Lo comencé a desarrollar pero no estoy seguro si es que estoy implementando de la manera adecuada esta parte del código. como dato adicional, el proyecto es ejecutado en internet explorer 8, ya que de esa forma debe ser realizado. agradecería cualquier ayuda!

```
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "MetodoController", data: parametros1,
    success: function(numeroRetornado) {
        if (numeroRetornado == 1) {
            $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "SegundoMetodoController", data: parametros2,
                success: function(json) {
                    $("#gridViewEjemplo").loadLocalData(json);
                }
            });
        }
        else{
           alert("¡Ha ocurrido un error!")
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: Hoa @Fran me parece que esta bien ¿a que viene la pregunta? ¿has encontrado algún problema al momento de ejecutar? como dato adicional te recomiendo que uses tecnologías mas nuevas para trabajar tus peticiones, como fetch que realmente no se si es soportado por IE8 pero tienes el polyfill a disposición, digo siempre es mejor que usar JQuery, actualmente mientras mas limpio de librearías obsoletas sea tu proyecto, mejor, un saludo.

Comment: Para usar tus url params con fetch puedes concatenarlos directamente a la url en formato de url normal o urlencoded, si no, puedes mapear el json de tus params y convertirlos a url dinamicamente [mira este ejemplo](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/256#issuecomment-241613757).

Comment: Hola @Dєηyη Crawford, gracias por la ayuda. Creo que podría ser útil tu ejemplo y muchos mas posiblemente, pero olvide mencionar que son las librerías ocupadas en la empresa en donde trabajo, por lo que hay pocas posibilidades de reemplazarlas. ¡Muchas gracias por la ayuda! un saludo.